# Using MAX in GROUP_CONCAT

Tags: mysql, group-by, max, group-concat

I have a problem related to the `Invalid use of group function` in MySQL.

The query I'm trying to execute is this (and I know that is a very huge query, but if I can execute this, then I'll adjust and fix for performance and easy reading stuff):

```
SELECT
    `id_c` AS `sceneId`,
    `scene`.`id` AS `sceneName`,
    `scene`.`frameCount` AS `frames`,
    task.id_mv AS `id_mv`,
    CONCAT( '[',GROUP_CONCAT(
        CONCAT( 
            '{',
                '"idTk": ', `task`.`id_tk`, ', ',
                -- '"tktype": ', `task`.`id_tk_type`, ', ',
                -- '"subDepType": ', IF ( `task`.`id_sub_dep_type` = 54, `task`.`id_sub_dep_type`, 'null'), ', ',
                -- '"color": "', `task`.`color`, '", ',
                '"weight": ', MAX(`task`.`weight`), ', ',
                '"dept": ', '"',
                    CASE `task`.`id_tk_type`
                        WHEN 43 THEN 'MVB'
                        WHEN 12 THEN 'LYT'
                        WHEN 32 THEN
                            CONCAT_WS(
                                ', ',
                                IF( `task`.`id_sub_dep_type` != 54, 'ANI', NULL ),
                                IF( `task`.`id_sub_dep_type` = 54, 'CKD', NULL )
                            )
                        WHEN 190 THEN 'DYN'
                        WHEN 104 THEN 'FIN'
                        WHEN 191 THEN 'LGT'
                    END, '"',
                -- task.id_tk_type, ', ',
                -- task.id_sub_dep_type,            
            '}'
        )
        ORDER BY
            FIELD( `task`.`id_tk_type`, 43, 12, 32, 190, 104, 191 ),
            `task`.`weight` DESC
        SEPARATOR
            ', '
    ), ']') AS `tkInfo`
FROM
        `V_task` AS `task`
        JOIN `tk_fct_mcsc` AS `mcsc` ON `task`.`id_tk` = `mcsc`.`id_tk`
        JOIN `scene` ON `mcsc`.`id_c` = `scene`.`id_scene`
WHERE
    `task`.`id_sub_dep_type` IN (
        SELECT
            `id_sub_dep_type`
        FROM
            `tk_dim_sub_dep_type`
        WHERE `id_tk_type` IN (
            SELECT
                `id_tk_type`
            FROM
                `tk_dim_dep_type`
            WHERE
                `id_tk_type` IN ( 43, 12, 32, 190, 104, 191 )
        )
              AND `id_sub_dep_type` != 54
        UNION
        SELECT
            `id_sub_dep_type`
        FROM
            `tk_dim_sub_dep_type`
        WHERE
            `id_sub_dep_type` = 54
    )
    AND `task`.`is_appr` = FALSE
    AND `mcsc`.`type` = 'sc'
    AND `scene`.`id` != '000'
    -- AND `mcsc`.`id_b` = 530
GROUP BY
    `scene`.`id`,
    `scene`.`id_scene`
    -- task.weight
ORDER BY
    `scene`.`id`,
    `task`.`weight` DESC;
```

The error, I know is the `MAX( task.weight )` inside the `GROUP_CONCAT` function, but I don't know how to avoid this thing..

I'm actually trying to build some sort of sqlfiddle thing to let you test this stuff, but what I need I think is just another pairs of eye that let me know where to see.

Thanks!

**EDIT # 1**
As [kickstart](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1723545/kickstart) asked, what I whant to obtain is something like that:

```
sceneId sceneName   frames  id_mv   tkInfo
200     001         1200    1       "[{"dept": "LGT"}, {"dept": "LGT"}]"
1342    001         45      14      "[{"dept": "LYT"}, {"dept": "LGT"}, {"dept": "LGT"}]"
1335    001         460     14      "[{"dept": "MVB"}, {"dept": "LYT"}, {"dept": "LGT"}, {"dept": "LGT"}]"
1351    001         20      11      "[{"dept": "LYT"}, {"dept": "ANI"}, {"dept": "FIN"}, {"dept": "LGT"}]"
1375    001         63      11      "[{"dept": "LYT"}, {"dept": "CKD"}, {"dept": "ANI"}, {"dept": "DYN"}, {"dept": "FIN"}, {"dept": "FIN"}, {"dept": "FIN"}, {"dept": "LGT"}]"
1382    001         66      11      "[{"dept": "LYT"}, {"dept": "CKD"}, {"dept": "ANI"}, {"dept": "FIN"}]"
```

But, without the repetition for the "dept", and to do so, i need the MAX weight fot that dept.

**EDIT # 2**
I have solved this problem of mine with a little cheat.

First, i have simplified a lot the main query, deleted the case-thing and inserted a MAX(weight) for each sceneId.

The, with this simplified query I have built a View, and with that view I have applied the case/group_concat thing.. and all the results are just fine.

[ ..sqlfiddle will be inserted in no time HERE.. ]

Comment: What is it you are trying to get? Surely your current code is trying to find a max weight for the group, and then trying to concatenate the values within the same group. But that would mean grouping the results twice. If you do manage it, you have a max task weight, but how does that relate to the other values from task table which might come from other rows

Comment: @Kickstart I have edited my question, and I hope this is more clear, to you. I have not showed the "complete" JSON string for `tkInfo` because the specific weight is irrelevant for my purpose. All I need is to get the MAX weight for each dept, instead of repeating the depts for each weight value.

Comment: `id_c AS sceneId, scene.id AS sceneName` -I'm not touching this one

Comment: @Strawberry haha.. I'm not the DB creator.. I'm actually using this stuff, but I don't know who has set the column names for the tables..

Comment: You need to effectively do the query twice, one for most of the details and again to get the max weight by department, then join the results and concatenate the final column.

Comment: I was thinking about the "`DISTINCT`" in the `group_concat`..
I mean, in the "`ORDER BY`" I have already asked for the `DESC` order by weight, and if I perform a distinct in the `GROUP_CONCAT` I should obtain all of the value I need with no repetition in the dept.. am I right? _**PS**_ I have done some test, and I have obtained something like the result I'm looking for, but I'm not sure about that.

Comment: DISTINCT will give you the distinct values in the GROUP_CONCAT, but I can't see how that will help you to pick one of several non distinct weights.

Comment: Slightly concerned about your 2nd edit, as it sounds almost like you are getting the max weight along with other fields which are neither aggregate fields or in the GROUP BY.

Answer (score 1):

Having a bit of a play, and (very) untested, but think you would need to effectively do the query twice. Once to get the details and once to get the max weight. You could move some of your sub selects around (doing a join - the union will take care of duplicates before the join).

Something like this:-

```
SELECT
    Sub1.id_c AS sceneId,
    Sub1.id AS sceneName,
    Sub1.frameCount AS frames,
    Sub1.id_mv AS id_mv,
    CONCAT( '[',GROUP_CONCAT(
        CONCAT( 
            '{',
                '"idTk": ', Sub1.id_tk, ', ',
                '"weight": ', Sub2.MaxTaskWeight, ', ',
                '"dept": ', '"', Sub1.id_tk_type_decode, '"',
            '}'
        )
        ORDER BY
            FIELD( Sub1.id_tk_type, 43, 12, 32, 190, 104, 191 ),
            Sub2.MaxTaskWeight DESC
        SEPARATOR
            ', '
    ), ']') AS tkInfo
FROM
(
    SELECT
        id_c AS sceneId,
        scene.id AS sceneName,
        scene.frameCount AS frames,
        task.id_mv AS id_mv,
        task.id_tk, 
        CASE task.id_tk_type
            WHEN 43 THEN 'MVB'
            WHEN 12 THEN 'LYT'
            WHEN 32 THEN IF( task.id_sub_dep_type = 54, 'CKD', 'ANI' )
            WHEN 190 THEN 'DYN'
            WHEN 104 THEN 'FIN'
            WHEN 191 THEN 'LGT'
        END AS id_tk_type_decode,
        task.id_tk_type
    FROM    V_task AS task
    INNER JOIN  tk_fct_mcsc AS mcsc ON task.id_tk = mcsc.id_tk
    INNER JOIN  scene ON mcsc.id_c = scene.id_scene
    INNER JOIN 
    (   
        SELECT id_sub_dep_type
        FROM tk_dim_sub_dep_type 
        INNER JOIN tk_dim_dep_type
        ON tk_dim_sub_dep_type.id_tk_type = tk_dim_dep_type.id_tk_type
        WHERE  tk_dim_dep_type.id_tk_type  IN ( 43, 12, 32, 190, 104, 191 )
        AND tk_dim_sub_dep_type.id_sub_dep_type != 54
        UNION
        SELECT id_sub_dep_type
        FROM tk_dim_sub_dep_type 
        WHERE id_sub_dep_type = 54
    ) Sub1
    ON task.id_sub_dep_type = Sub1.id_sub_dep_type
    WHERE task.is_appr = FALSE
    AND mcsc.`type` = 'sc'
    AND scene.`id` != '000'
)
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT scene.id, scene.id_scene, MAX(task.weight) AS MaxTaskWeight
    FROM    V_task AS task
    INNER JOIN  tk_fct_mcsc AS mcsc ON task.id_tk = mcsc.id_tk
    INNER JOIN  scene ON mcsc.id_c = scene.id_scene
    INNER JOIN 
    (   
        SELECT id_sub_dep_type
        FROM tk_dim_sub_dep_type 
        INNER JOIN tk_dim_dep_type
        ON tk_dim_sub_dep_type.id_tk_type = tk_dim_dep_type.id_tk_type
        WHERE  tk_dim_dep_type.id_tk_type  IN ( 43, 12, 32, 190, 104, 191 )
        AND tk_dim_sub_dep_type.id_sub_dep_type != 54
        UNION
        SELECT id_sub_dep_type
        FROM tk_dim_sub_dep_type 
        WHERE id_sub_dep_type = 54
    ) Sub1
    ON task.id_sub_dep_type = Sub1.id_sub_dep_type
    WHERE task.is_appr = FALSE
    AND mcsc.`type` = 'sc'
    AND scene.`id` != '000'
    GROUP BY scene.id, scene.id_scene 
) Sub2
ON Sub1.id = Sub2.id
AND Sub1.id_scene = Sub2.id_scene
GROUP BY
    Sub1.id,
    Sub1.id_scene
ORDER BY
    Sub1.id,
    MaxTaskWeight DESC;
```

Comment: Ok, this is something big. And I was thinking about performances.
Thanks a lot for your help, but now I have this question about the DISTINCT in the GROUP_CONCAT that maybe can help me solve this query-thing without this HUGE help of yours. I need to test it more.

Comment: I don't know you data, so it might be possible to simplify the 2nd query but not by much.